# Define function with any kind of parameters and known return type

Tags: scala, function, types, parameters

I am sure something like this should exist and that I just don't know how to phrase it.

So is there a way to define a generalized function which can take any number of parameters (from zero) of any type and return a value of known type? So if we define

```
f: <something_here> => Int
```

Any function that returns `Int` shall satisfy this than.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not, without losing type-safety (assuming I understand your question correctly). Ultimately, the only way to use a value of type e.g. `String => Int` is to supply a `String` to its `apply` method, but how would you know what type of arguments to supply to "Any function that returns `Int`"?

If you are willing to lose type-safety (you shouldn't), you can achieve it with something like

```
class UnsafeFunction[A] {
  def apply(xs: Any*): A
}

object UnsafeFunction {
  implicit def fromF1[A, B](f: A => B): UnsafeFunction[B] = new UnsafeFunction[B] { 
    def apply(xs: Any*) = f(xs(0).asInstanceOf[A])
  }
  implicit def fromF2[A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C): UnsafeFunction[C] = new UnsafeFunction[C] { 
    def apply(xs: Any*) = f(xs(0).asInstanceOf[A], xs(1).asInstanceOf[B])
  }
  ...
}
```

This allows assigning any function which returns `Int` to a value of type `UnsafeFunction[Int]`, or passing it to a method which takes such arguments. Again, I very much don't suggest using this in practice.

What you *can* usefully do is use generic types such as `A => Int` and `(A, B) => Int`, where `A` is a type parameter of your type or method. Scala itself doesn't allow you to unify functions with different *number* of parameters, but there is a library which does: [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#facilities-for-abstracting-over-arity). Unfortunately, using it is far from trivial.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would do it:

```
def f[T](x:T*): Int = ???
```

It takes any number of arguments of type `T` and returns an `Int`. In the function you'd get access to variable `x` as `Seq[T]`, so can process the parameters accordingly.

But you might want to define the upper bound for type `T`, depending on what you'd like to do with them.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function which can take `Any` as a parameter and Int as return type
e.g.

```
def f(x: Any*) : Int = x.length
```

above function takes any number of parameters of any type and returns number of parameters passed
You can execute it as -

```
f(1,2,3) // This will return 3
f(1,'b') // This will return 2
```

Hope this clarifies your doubt!

Answer (score 0):

In Scala 3, you could take advantage of parameter untupling.

[Docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/other-new-features/parameter-untupling.html)

```scala
type F = Tuple => Int
```

It takes a `Tuple` trait, and that could mean any number of parameters of any type.